# How to select the highest value after a count() | Sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, max

This is my query:

```
SELECT f.name, COUNT(*) as num_books
from author f
JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
Group by f.name
```

Which gives me this table:

```
NAME                                                NUM_BOOKS
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Dyremann                                                    2
Nam mann                                                    1
Thomas                                                      1
Asgeir                                                      1
Tullemann                                                   5
Plantemann                                                  1
Beste forfatter                                             1
Fagmann                                                     5
Lars                                                        1
Hans                                                        1
Svein Arne                                                  1
```

How could I easly alter the query to only display the author with the highest amount of released books? (While keeping in mind I'm rather new to sql)

Comment: DB version? `select * from v$version;`

Comment: What do you want to do in case you have more than a single top author?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production , Which is probably why your oracle 12c didn't work

Comment: I woulnd't mind showing all the top authors

Comment: I've added additional option to the answer

Comment: Thanks alot again,  Would you mind if i asked you another question as a side part to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126266/discussion-between-peebl-and-dudu-markovitz).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle, and as far as I know - only Oracle, allows you to nest two aggregate functions.

```
SELECT max (f.name) keep (dense_rank last order by count (*)) as name
from author f
JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
Group by f.name
```

In order to get **ALL** top authors:

```
select   name
from    (SELECT f.name,rank () over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
         from author f
         JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
         Group by f.name
         ) 
 where   rnk = 1
```

Since Oracle 12c:

```
SELECT f.name
from author f
JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
Group by f.name
order by count (*) desc
fetch first row /* with ties (optional, in order to get all top authors) */
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm.  However, how would i change the text above the display? Which i changed before with an AS, I couldn¨t find anywhere to fit the AS now.

Comment: You're welcome. the **AS** comes always at the end of the expression. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Must be a random space or somthing in my name then. It didn't work the first time i tried. Thank you though!

Comment: If you want to use an alias with spaces or special characters you can surround it with double quotes, e.g. `as "this is a special alias!"`

Comment: The "fetch first row" solution (Oracle 12) will miss ties at the top (I think).

Comment: You can see the optional **with ties** at the comment

Comment: Aha! Yes, I will see it (if I look). Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do is to use:

```
SELECT f.name, COUNT(*) as num_books
from author f
JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
Group by f.name
Order by num_books DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

This will order the results from biggest to smallest and return the first result.

Comment: This will work only for Oracle 12 and above - and it will miss ties for "most books".

Answer (score 1):

1) Oracle Specific : ( Using ROWNUM, For Postgres/MySql use limit )

```
select * from 
(SELECT f.name, COUNT(*) as num_books
from author f
JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
Group by f.name order by num_books desc )
 where ROWNUM = 1
```

2) General Query for all databases :

```
select f.name,count(*) as max_num_books from author f
JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
Group by f.name
having count(*) = 
(select max(num_books) 
from 
(SELECT f.name, COUNT(*) as num_books
from author f
JOIN book b on b.tittle = f.book
Group by f.name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need a join in the first place. It appears that the `author` table has a column `book` - why is it not enough to `count(book)` from that table, grouping by `name`? This arrangement is very strange - the `author` table should only have author properties, the author name should be in the `title` table, but you do join on `author.book = book.title` which seems to suggest that you do, in fact, have that strange arrangement (and therefore you don't need a join). Also, having a table and a column (in another table) share the same name, `book`, is a practice best to be avoided.

The most elementary solution (not the most efficient though), in this case, is

```
select name, count(book) as max_num_books
from   author
group by name
having count(book) = (select max(count(book) from author group by name);
```

The subquery groups by name, and then it selects the max over all group counts. The outer query selects the names that have a book count equal to this maximum. The subquery returns a single row in a single column - a single value. Such a query is called a "scalar" subquery and can be used wherever a single value is needed, such as the HAVING clause of the outer query. (It's in the HAVING clause and not a WHERE clause, since it refers to group properties - `count(book)` - and not to individual row properties).

The more efficient solution is as Dudu showed:

```
select name, ct as max_num_books
from   ( select name, count(*) as ct, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
         from   author
         group by name
       )
where rnk = 1;
```